# Can't acess xfce4 from crouton suddenly on acer chromebook 15

Tags: updates, xfce, chromebook, crouton

```
Loading extra module: /usr/share/crosh/dev.d/50-crosh.sh
Welcome to crosh, the Chrome OS developer shell.

If you got here by mistake, don't panic!  Just close this tab and carry on.

Type 'help' for a list of commands.

If you want to customize the look/behavior, you can use the options page.
Load it by using the Ctrl+Shift+P keyboard shortcut.

crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startxfce4
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.

X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 31 22:07:48 PDT 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 3584000 verity payload=PARTUUID=1bd15e32-2992-d849-98db-9b3f134a4afb/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=1bd15e32-2992-d849-98db-9b3f134a4afb/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=3584000 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=a10b60a9429fc895093ffd0e5e68ee9d0247e61f salt=daefda212e1fad73b5b94f147e155dda617674c8eeb19f772b00eb224775242c" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=1bd15e32-2992-d849-98db-9b3f134a4afb add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:59:06PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.11 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Mon Nov 13 10:06:03 2017
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Unable to set master
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "TakeDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...
chronos@localhost / $
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem/message today, using Acer Chromebook 14. It was all good before. Do you know more?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem following these steps from https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Common-issues-and-reporting.

Remove any existing installer from your Downloads folder.
Fetch a fresh installer

Open a crosh shell (Ctrl-Alt-T, then type shell)

Figure out the name of your chroot(s).

If you do not know, `sudo edit-chroot -a` (on recent enough crouton), or `sudo ls /usr/local/chroots` will provide you with a list of chroot names.
Run an update: `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -n chrootname -u`, where chrootname is the name of your chroot, make sure there are no errors.
Reboot: shutdown completely and restart.
Try starting your chroot again.